# SOpt está saindo do BETA?

Tags: suporte, beta

Recebi hoje um e-mail informando sobre a graduação do SOpt.

É verdade?
Quais as principais mudanças?
Quando vai acontecer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É verdade. Vamos sair do Beta esse mês!
Mais detalhes aqui:

[Prepare o capelo e a beca](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2201/12)